# Object not pushing correctly into array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to push an object in to an array in a jQuery `$.each` loop but when I try to push an object into an array it does not store correctly and it overwrites what was previously in the array.

The code looks like this:

```
var ing = {};
var mData = [];

$.post('find.php', {levels:levels}, function(res){
        var resData = $.parseJSON(res);
        if (resData.success == true){

            var mName = resData.m_name;
            var p = resData.p;
            $.each(p, function(key,val){

                ing.name = val.name;
                ing.weight = val.weight;
                ing.i_count = val.i_total;
                ing.l_count = val.l_total;
                //console.log(ing);
                mData.push(ing);
                //console.log(mData);
            });

        }
    });
 console.log(mData);
```

The `ing` variable shows the data I would expect every time in the loop however when the data gets pushed into the array the first index of the array gets overwritten by the second index, which results in something like this.

```
 { name="tea", weight="250", i_count=26, l_count = 1},{ name="tea", weight="250", i_count=26, l_count = 1}
```

So my question is what is wrong with the way I am pushing the data into the array?

Comment: and what return find.php? maybe you can post a console.log of resData before each loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared ing variable outside the `$.each` method. this effectively overrides each time.
Declare it inside the `$.each` loop code.

```
$.each(p, function(key,val){
  var ing = {}
   ...
   ... update ing variable
```